# Accessing unity container of web app from a class library

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, unity-container

I have a class library for caching ( Redis ), we have a unity container inside this Redis class library

```
public class TCache<T>
{
    static readonly IUnityContainer container = new UnityContainer();

    private ITCache<T> ICacheStore;
    static TCache()
    {
        container.RegisterType<ITCache<T>, TRedisCacheStore<T>>(new ContainerControlledLifetimeManager());
    }
    public TCache()
    {
        ICacheStore = container.Resolve<TRedisCacheStore<T>>();
    }
```

Now my senior said me not use a separate container like this and I should be using the container which is already created inside the web app with the reason being that there should be only one single container.

**My question is:** is it possible to access a unity container that resides in a different project and is it necessary to do this change ?

**Note:** I cannot add the reference of the web app into the Redis cache class library.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should only reference a container within your **composition root** (http://blog.ploeh.dk/2011/07/28/CompositionRoot/).

In other words, find where your current services are registered, and perform the generic registration there.

Your type that requires a cache store then takes your abstraction via constructor injection:

```
public class Cache<T>
{
  private readonly ITCache<T> cacheStore;

  public Cache(ITCache<T> cacheStore)
  {
      this.cacheStore = cacheStore 
          ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(cacheStore));
  }
}
```

By the way, using `T` as a prefix for your types (rather than as a prefix for generic type parameters) is very confusing.

The names `TCache` and `ITCache` are also very confusing.

Comment: I think i got my answer from this link http://blog.ploeh.dk/2011/07/28/CompositionRoot/

Comment: I was trying to reference container outside the composition root, the link says "Only applications should have Composition Roots. Libraries and frameworks shouldn't."

Comment: Thanks @devdigital

Answer (score 0):

Well, I share his view of the usage of the container. How I fixed this issue is (without going into the details of how I actually created it):

Make an option to register onto the container through an interface. Something like IRegisterContainer.Register(IUnityContainer container).

Then at the moment where you now register the mappings to the container, you extend that function to also search your assembly for all objects that implement that IRegisterContainer and make them register themselves.

And use this as a platform to fix your problem.

If you want to use the IUnityContainer in your TCache object to resolve the TRediscacheStore. Simply let the IUnityContainer register itself.

```
container.Register<IUnityContainer, container>().
```

And make it a dependency in the constructor of TCache.

Comment: The second one sounds like a solution let me try that, can you please let me know the implications of using this.

Comment: Haha, I don't know. I have never thought about multiple containers registered in a single container. I mean why not. It actually makes scoped containers but I don't really see the advantage of this compared to just simply having one container.

Comment: Because when resolving your container you also have to give the main container, then resolve with a name. I think this only further complicates the implementation of inversion of control instead of simplifying it to it's most workable condition.

Comment: Thanks let me try this.